# A fast way to decide satisfiability of a set of simple fewnomial inequalities?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, ac.commutative-algebra, algorithms

### Background

Considering a set of points $(x_i, y_i)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ and constraints between some triples of them, which state, whether the three points of the triple are oriented clockwise (R), counter-clockwise (L) or collinear (I), we can translate this into a set of inequalities of the form

$x_1 y_2 - x_1 y_3 - x_2 y_1 + x_2 y_3 + x_3 y_1 - x_3 y_2 < 0$

$x_1 y_2 - x_1 y_3 - x_2 y_1 + x_2 y_3 + x_3 y_1 - x_3 y_2 > 0$

$x_1 y_2 - x_1 y_3 - x_2 y_1 + x_2 y_3 + x_3 y_1 - x_3 y_2 = 0$

for (R), (L) and (I) respectively, where the polynomials on the left-hand side are obtained from the determinant

$\det \begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_1 & y_1 \newline
1 & x_2 & y_2 \newline
1 & x_3 & y_3
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
x_2 - x_1 \newline y_2 - y_1
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
y_3 - y_1 \newline x_1 - x_3
\end{pmatrix}
$.

---

So the set of constraints is satisfiable iff the corresponding system of (in-)equalities is satisfiable.
Although this problem is NP-hard, i am interested in the following:

> What is a (relatively) fast way to decide satisfiability of such a system of (in-)equalities?

Kind regards.

Comment: I'm unsure how to tag this. Glad for any advice.

Comment: You are misusing the term "fewnomial" here:  fewnomials refer to polynomials which have arbitrarily high degree, but the number of monomials is independent on that degree. Here, you have only degree 2...

Comment: It looks like you have it already: compute differences, take dot products, pay attention to signs.  Unless the constraints fit some pattern like disjoint triples, I don't see any nonobvious parallelization or other optimizations.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.10.19 

Comment: I expect that there is a polynomial-time (polynomial number of real arithmetic operations) algorithms to do this, but I don't really have time to dot all the i's and cross all the t's right now. But what I have in mind is not easily implemented or available as a black-box, so it depends on if you actually want to use such an algorithm, or simply know it exists.

Comment: @Thierry Zell: Interesting. I was not able to find a definition of the term fewnomial. All i could find, was theorems that state that the number of nondegenerate roots of a polynomial does not depend on the degree of the polynomial. I don't understand the definition you give above. How can the number of monomials of a polynomial be dependent on the degree of the polynomial?

Comment: Well, if you consider dense polynomials, say homogeneous of degree d in n variables, then the number of monomials is n+d-1 choose n-1. So it grows polynomially with the degree. The idea behind fewnomials (due to Khovanskii) is to look instead at a fixed number of monomials, but for which the degrees are unknown (i.e. can be arbitrarily large). SO for instance $x^N+x+1$ would be a fewnomial, and indeed, the number of real roots of this polynomial is 0 or 1, whatever the value of $N$ may be.

Comment: @Thierry Zell: As i understand Khovanskii's Bound, it only requires that the number $n$ of variables and the number $k$ of distinct monomials in the system of polynomials grow at most linear with the number of polynomials in the system. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your problem is NP-hard.
If you had, not just triples-constraints for *some* triples, but had given the
orientation of *every* triple, then you have specified what is known as the combinatorial *order type*
of the point configuration. (See [Handbook of Discrete and Computational Geometry](http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781584883012), Chapter 5,
"Pseudoline arrangements.") This is equivalent (in some sense) to a rank-3 [oriented matroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriented_matroid#Geometry).
It is NP-hard to determine whether or not an oriented matroid is realizable by points in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  This was established in a 1991 paper by Peter Shor, "Stretchability of pseudolines is NP-hard"
([PDF link](http://math.mit.edu/~shor/papers/Stretchability_NP-hard.pdf)).
Jürgen Richter-Gebert's Ph.D. thesis was on this topic:
"On the realizability problem of combinatorial geometries—Decision methods," 1992.

**Update**. To respond to the request for more specific information, let me suggest
Günter Ziegler's 1996 article, "Oriented Matroids Today" ([PDF link](http://www.combinatorics.org/Surveys/ds4.pdf)), Section 3.4, "Realization algorithms," where he says,

> the most eﬃcient algorithm (in practice) currently available to ﬁnd a realization (if one exists) 
>   is the iterative “rubber band” algorithm described in Pock [532].

As you can infer from the number 532, this article has a comprehensive bibliography!

I might also recommend looking at Aichholzer et al.'s 2001 paper,
"[Enumerating Order Types for Small Point Sets with Applications](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=378596),"
which includes a clear exposition of the relationship between order types and
pseudoline arrangements.  Oswin Aichholzer maintains a very nice [Order Type web page](http://www.ist.tugraz.at/staff/aichholzer//research/rp/triangulations/ordertypes/), which
is worth visiting for the latest information.  There you will learn that there are exactly
2,334,512,907 order types of 11-point sets.

Comment: Thank you for the references! In this handbook Richter-Gebert gives the complexity for the best know algorithm to decide the realizability of a given oriented matroid. But he does not give the actual algorithm. And i cannot find it in the handbook. Do you have any suggestion where i could find a description of that algorithm or any other good algorithm for that problem?

Comment: I've now added some more information.  Perhaps start at Aichholzer's Order Type web page, which is quite current, and work chronologically backward.

Comment: I was not able to get a copy of the thesis of Pock. I even asked at the University on which it was written. Does anyone know a source for it?